# mysql table is not committed by commit() after delete row

Tags: python, mysql-python

I am trying to delete multiple rows in mysql table, through a loop in python. There is no error message but finally the table is not being updated. My code is:

```
import mysql.connector

mydb = mysql.connector.connect(
    host="localhost",
    user="root",
    password="1234",
    database="Share")
mycursor = mydb.cursor()

for i in range(288, 297):
    sql = "DELETE from name_list where ID = " + str(i)
    mycursor.execute(sql)
mydb.commit()

mycursor.execute("SELECT * from Share.name_list")
for row in mycursor.fetchall() :
    print(row)
```

Thanks

Comment: The table is same before and after running this code.

Comment: **WARNING!!** Do **never** concatenate strings and pass them as SQL-statements! Even if it might be safe in this example, it's easy to forget about it and make changes that make creates major security flaws. You have to make it a consistent habit to use parameterized queries (as Robin Nemeth does in the answer below). Otherwise, you might expose yourself to [SQL-injections](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection).

Comment: Thank U very much for your kind response. I must be benefited by your advice. Thanks again.

Answer (score 3):

How about this?

```
for i in range(288, 297):
    sql = "DELETE from name_list where ID = %s"
    mycursor.execute(sql, (i, ))
mydb.commit()
```

[source](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-python/en/connector-python-api-mysqlcursor-execute.html)

this should automatically quote the variable based on the datatype and has the added benefit of sql injection protection.
In this case it doesn't matter, since the parameter is always generated by `range()` but concatenating variables into sql queries manually is generally bad habit.

Comment: I would put some more emphasize on the last part. It isn't a bad habit equivalent to smoking, but more like taking naps while driving.